# How can I scale to the center?

Tags: scale

[image]

How can I scale proportionally into the center? For some reason it keeps going to which ever edge or vertex was first selected when making the edge loop.

Comment: Hi. This is very basic functionality. I am happy if I can help with that, however it might be easier for you to watch some beginner video tutorials on YouTube to get the basic stuff out of the way. I think that may be faster and more efficient to learn while watching video tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You have pivot point set to Active Element and the first vertex you select when selecting a loop is the active element. To scale to the center you would need to set transform pivot to Median Point or to Bounding Box Center. You can switch the type of pivot point for transform operations like rotate, move or scale at the header of any 3D View window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Martin. Yes i will go back to understand the fundamentals of the program. I hadn't encountered this issue before so i knew i clicked something by accident.